# Unable to upload file using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to upload a file through AJAX. I have searched over a lot but found examples using form submit only, but I can not use form submit. I have tried several examples but nothing reaches my server. When I tried [this link](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx), it worked but again it was through a form submission.

Here is the piece of code relevant to the context

**JS Code**

```
function _upload(filedata) {
    $.ajax({
        url: './myURI',
        data: filedata,
        type: 'POST',

        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
        mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',    //Property added in 1.5.1

        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
$("#cpc-uploadBtn").click(function (evt) {
                var data;
                data = new FormData();
                data.append('file', $('#cpc-upload')[0].files[0]);
                _upload(data);

            });
```

**HTML Part**

```
    <input id="cpc-upload" name="file" type="file" />
    <button id="cpc-uploadBtn" type="button">Upload</button>
```

### Edit

Is there any other way to do this without using form submit and formdata?

Comment: What is the reason you can't use form submit?

Comment: I can not sue form submit as it expects a view in return but I expect a success/failure string once the request is served

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Safari/FireFox (only those support `FormData`), you need to modify your `$.ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: './myURI',
    data: filedata,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Seeting `contentType` option to false will force jQuery not to add a Content-Type header for you (otherwise the boundary string will be missing from it). Also the `processData` flag must be set to false so jQuery will not try to convert your `FormData` into a string.

Now if you know that your clients are using HTML5 you should try using new JavaScript File API - check following articles:

- [Working with files in JavaScript, Part 1: The Basics](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/05/08/working-with-files-in-javascript-part-1/)
- [Working with files in JavaScript, Part 2: FileReader](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/05/15/working-with-files-in-javascript-part-2/)
- [Working with files in JavaScript, Part 3: Progress events and errors](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/05/22/working-with-files-in-javascript-part-3/)
- [Working with files in JavaScript, Part 4: Object URLs](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/05/31/working-with-files-in-javascript-part-4-object-urls/)
- [Working with files in JavaScript, Part 5: Blobs](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/06/05/working-with-files-in-javascript-part-5-blobs/)

In all other cases you are forced to use custom plugins, for example:

- [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)
- [jQuery Form Plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose currently FormData objects are only supported in Safari/Firefox, it has not been adopted by most of the browsers yet.

I recently struggled a lot finding ajax file uploader for asp.net and I am currently using this one in my project:

https://github.com/valums/file-uploader

Answer (score 0):

there is a small alternative if you want to use

```
<script>
    // wait for the DOM to be loaded
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function
       $("#tempForm").ajaxForm({
       url:'../calling action or servlet',
       type:'post',
       beforeSend:function()
       {
         alert("perform action before making the ajax call like showing soinner image");
       },
       success:function(e){
        alert("data is"+e);
            alert("now do whatever you want with the data");
       }
       });
    });
</script>
```

you can find the plugin [here](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#download)

Comment: I can not use any plugin. PLease update your answer if there is any other work around?